# Jack polynomial and Selberg integral

Tags: co.combinatorics, mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, algebraic-combinatorics

I am studying the generalisation of the Selberg's integral by using Jack polynomial as outlined by Forrester and Warnaar ([arXiv: 0710.3981](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.3981)). They write down the *symmetric* Jack polynomial as 
\begin{equation}
P_\lambda^{(\alpha)} = m_\lambda + \sum_{\mu < \lambda}a_{\lambda \mu} m_\mu
\end{equation}
where $m_\lambda$ is the monomial symmetric function for the partition $\lambda$. I basically want to play around with the equation number (2.46) in the reference mentioned above. Could someone give me examples of simple Jack polynomials? Also, I don't understand the significance of the parameter $\alpha$ in $P_\lambda^{(\alpha)}$.

Comment: Jack polynomials are a family of symmetric polynomials with one parameter, here called $\alpha$. At $\alpha=1$ you get Schur, and for $\alpha=2$ zonal symmetric polynomials. (Jack polynomials are in turn generalised Macdonald polynomials, from which they are obtained by setting $t = q^\alpha$ and letting $q \to 1$.)

Comment: PS. Lest it might confuse someone let me correct my previous comment: in Macdonald's notation it's $q=t^{\alpha}$, rather than the reverse. (This is related to the coupling of the quantum Calogero--Sutherland model $g\,(g-1)$ as $g=1/\alpha$.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this set of notes on the Jack symmetric functions / polynomials: https://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2016/11/27/a-note-on-the-jack-symmetric-functions-polynomials/

Comment: So basically the coefficients $a_{\lambda\mu}$ get fixed in terms of the parameter $\alpha$, right?

Comment: Yep. That is right.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!